# Windows 10 Will Not Boot After Partitioning

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, reinstall, partition-recovery

I had Linux installed on my ssd which was taking up too much space and wanted to get rid of it. After going into a partitioning application I deleted the Linux partitions and the Windows boot manager by accident. I'm an idiot. Now a I get when I boot into the only boot option left on the ssd (windows 10) I get a flashing small white line and the top left of my screen.

I'm fine with reinstalling windows, but is there any way to transfer all my files and apps from the broken windows into the new one? Also is there a fix for this without having to reinstall Windows? I tried troubleshooting with the windows 10 ISO but had no luck and I couldn't restore an older version of Windows. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot into a Live CD, which houses Linux in RAM and on a CD/DVD/USB. Most Linux distributions now support the NTFS file system. Assuming you deleted the smaller 100MB partition (and not the larger primary one), your data will still be very easily accessible. You will load up the Live CD and should be view the data partition and copy data in a normal fashion to a USB drive or other removable media.

If that proves not to be the case, you can attempt to rebuild the partition table with software from Active@ or EaseUS. Either company also provides software (among others) who will be able to scan the "raw" disk for files and recover them. There is open source software, but can be hit or miss in this regard.

From the sounds of things, if the "windows 10 ISO" couldn't find a Windows installation, you will have work ahead of yourself.